# What are the most popular android open source ui libraries

Tags: android, android-library

What are the most popular used android open source UI libraries used, like calendars, action-bar, widgets, graphs, utilities(barcode scanner, documents reader like .pdf and .doc), and

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. If you search around, you will find various collections of such things, such as http://androidviews.net

Comment: The most popular are all stored in one centralized repository [right here for quick access](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+are+the+most+popular+android+open+source+ui+libraries&oq=What+are+the+most+popular+android+open+source+ui+libraries&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4450j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You can find something interesting here: http://android-arsenal.com

Comment: In-case someone stops by this question, check this link: http://android-arsenal.com/
it has tons of useful libs for UI and other stuff :)

Comment: I would recommend checking out https://android.libhunt.com/categories . The libraries of every category are ordered by popularity on Github. It's a very extensive list and many people find it helpful.

Answer (score 15):

I do not know many, but definitely square libraries are worth to explore:

Libraries: Dagger, Otto, Retrofit, Okhttp, Butterknife, Flow, Mortar ...

You can find at: https://github.com/square

And some good libraries listed by CodePath: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries

And lots of libraries listed snowdream: https://github.com/snowdream/awesome-android

Comment: It's hard to beat squares libraries. It feels a bit to me like Square is filling in the gaps that Google leaves open. The only library I choose over something square makes is with event buses. I use the greenrobot eventbus over otto. I've never even looked at Otto though.